# How to use an inversion

Tags: subject-verb-inversion

The following passage comes from a [*Washington Post* article](https://www.washingtonpost.com/politics/melania-trump-saying-2-words-more-often-first-lady/2017/10/09/b470c606-acc3-11e7-9b93-b97043e57a22_story.html):

> It was a moment eight months in the making: "Melania Trump bounding down the White House lawn to the vegetable garden made famous by her predecessor."

I can't understand the context of passage.

Is above passage inversion of below passage?

> Bounding down the White House lawn to the vegetable garden made Melania Trump famous by her predecessor.

Comment: No, it was the vegetable garden that had been made famous. Presumably a previous First Lady took a special interest in it.

Comment: Please include links to anything you quote from the internet

Comment: It is not, and please explain how the Question belongs here and not, for instance, at English Language Learners?

Answer (score 1):

The [vegetable garden was made famous by Michelle Obama](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/White_House_Vegetable_Garden#Obama.E2.80.99s_vegetable_garden)

So your inversion is wrong.  It might help if you inserted some words, possibly

> Melania Trump [was seen] bounding down the White House lawn to the vegetable garden [which had been] made famous by her predecessor [Michelle Obama].